# Increase cell when another cell value change

Tags: microsoft-excel

In cell D1 the amount changes every month, therefore I would like cell E1 to increase due to the change in D1. What formula could I use to make this happen?

Example: Current Monthly activity is $500 in cell D1, Cell E1 currently has the value $1000 but it need to increase to 1500.

Comment: This cannot be done with Formula as it would create a circular reference.  Instead one would need to use vba in a Worksheet_Change Event.

Comment: Not familiar with worksheet change event any additional info would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: are you manually going to put 500 everymonth in cell d1?

Comment: Yes I will manually type in a different number each month.

Answer (score 2):

You can use iterative calculations in Excel:

[image]

Use the following formula in B1:

```
=B1+A1
```

Here's the effect:

[image]

Comment: Hi @Binggo_ MSFT,, better [edit] your post & explain the effect of ITERATION, will help the OP & others too,, +10☺